# Nullable Integer or int with a special value

Tags: java, null, field

Currently I am working on a library, which provides small and easily modifiable objects to users. However, some integer field could be set to `auto`/`inherit`. There are two basic solution to solve this: attach the special meaning to an invalid value (for example, `0` for a width/height field), or: use `Integer` instead of `int`, which can be null.

```
class SomeProperties {

    // C-style
    int someField = 0;

    // ...

}
```

---

```
class SomeProperties {

    // SQL-style
    Integer someField = null;

    // ...

}
```

Which should I use, taking into account to several aspects, in particular of readibility and performance?

Comment: Another option: use `Optional<Integer>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner: That's just more overhead on what `Integer` already brings to the table (with regard to the OP's specific use case).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder except that you can't accidentally use it somewhere that you expect a non-null `Integer`.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Meh, `isPresent` vs. `== null`, I just don't see that `Optional` brings anything to the table *in this case*. :-) Given the OP's concern about performance impacts just of boxing, for one thing.

Comment: @David: This back-and-forth with Andy is (in a very small way) why these sorts of questions are off-topic for SO. More:  [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I'd use the "SQL-style": Since you're obviously required to check for a special value in either case, you might as well check for `null` so you don't have to sacrifice an actual value as a sentinel.

Comment: There is a type that exists for this purpose: [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html)

Comment: @TJCrowder: I can accept that this is off-topic. But it is a little annoying to me, that find-me-the-mistake questions, to which the answer is easily found on Google, are more valuable than more abstract (but not less specific or technical) questions that can be answered only experienced people like SO users.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Nullable Integer, as it:

1. Doesn't reduce your range
2. Throws an exception in case you use it somewhere it shouldn't be used while invalid

This question is kind of opinion based though.